# drilldown not working in piecharts in reactjs

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Im trying to add the drilldown option to my piechart but the drilldown does not trigger.

HEre is my codesandbox.io

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-43bgg
```

Comment: Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-fsowo

Comment: Thanks.I'm trying to detect the drilldown event but still I doesn't work..Here is the updated version..https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-43bgg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the `drilldown` module and add the `drilldown` data also for each entity.

Please check updated code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-tq52i

To import the `drilldown` module:

```
import drilldow from "highcharts/modules/drilldown";

drilldow(Highcharts);
```

To add the drilldown data:

```
drilldown: {
    series: [
      {
        id: "DataA",
        data: [["v65.0", 0.1], ["v64.0", 1.3]]
      },

      {
        id: "DataB",
        data: [["v11.0", 6.2], ["v10.0", 0.29]]
      }
    ]
```

For each series, data add the `drilldown` id also.

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown

Comment: Thanks, I didn't set the drilldown option to true.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import and initialize the `drilldown` module:

```
import drilldown from "highcharts/modules/drilldown";

// init the module
drilldown(Highcharts);
```

---

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-a-module